# Python current time comparison with other time

Tags: python, datetime

I am looking for a comparison of two times in Python. One time is the real time from computer and the other time is stored in a string formatted like `"01:23:00"`.

```
import time

ctime = time.strptime("%H:%M:%S")   # this always takes system time
time2 = "08:00:00"

if (ctime > time2):
    print("foo")
```

Comment: Please fix the format of your question, and in addition, make it look like a question (at present, there is not a single question mark). Explain your code and whatever doesn't work in it.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare datetime strings, which will often give you the wrong answer as these will be compared lexicographically. Why not leave or convert them to datetime objects so you can directly compare them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

my_time_string = "01:20:33"
my_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time_string, "%H:%M:%S")

# I am supposing that the date must be the same as now
my_datetime = now.replace(hour=my_datetime.time().hour, minute=my_datetime.time().minute, second=my_datetime.time().second, microsecond=0)

if (now > my_datetime):
    print("Hello")
```

**EDIT:**

The above solution was not taking into account leap second days (`23:59:60`). Below is an updated version that deals with such cases:

```
import datetime
import calendar
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

my_time_string = "23:59:60" # leap second
my_time_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " " + my_time_string # I am supposing the date must be the same as now

my_time = time.strptime(my_time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

my_datetime = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=calendar.timegm(my_time))

if (now > my_datetime):
    print("Foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

The `datetime` module will parse dates, times, or combined date-time values into objects that can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(),"%H:%M:%S") #output: 11:12:12
mytime = "10:12:34"
if current_time >  mytime:
    print "Time has passed."
```

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically. I think you should compare datetime objects.

Comment: @felipeptcho In general, that is a much better thing to do. It's more guaranteed to be correct and probably faster. In this specific case, it's probably "safe" to do it the way described.

Comment: @Vatine I can see your solution is less verbose despite the probably low efficiency. That is good! But I am curious about why it's "probably safer".

Comment: @felipeptcho Not "probably safer", "probably safe". If you're using 24h time stamps (which %H as a format is), there's no time between '00:00:00' and '23:59:60' where the time comparison and string comparison should disagree. Why not formatting the times as string before comparoison would be faster? Less string conversion.

Comment: @Vatine Thanks for the explanation. Using time comparison `23:59:60` would not pass datetime validation and an exception would be thrown, which I think it's a good approach, because the exception could be handled and the user could be presented a message. On the other hand, using string comparison would not validate anything and would "incorrectly" display `00:00:00` as a time before `23:59:60`.

Comment: @felipeptcho That makes me sad, since "23:59:60" is an actual, valid time (but only in days that have a leap second) and within a single day, "00:00:00" is roughly 24 hours before "23:59:60".

Comment: @Vatine You are right about the leap second. I could see that Python supports leap seconds using the `time` module. I figured out a solution without giving up using `datetime` comparison, thus keeping time validation. I'll update my answer. Thanks!