# How to set a fixed opening hours in Python. I want to have opening time between 00.01 to 11.00 EU time

Tags: python, time

I need your help.

I have struggled to get order Python code.

I want open hours between 00.01 - 11.00. Every day. EU time.

I hope you can help me.

```
    today = DateTime.Now
    #Write from-time here, hour, minute, second
    fromTime =  Time(0, 1, 0)
    #Write to-time here, hour, minute, second
    toTime =  Time(11, 0, 0)
    isInTimeInterval=(today>=fromTime and today <= toTime)
    if (not isInTimeInterval):
        # It is closed
        return self.GetPage('stangd')

    return PageNode.GetNextPage(self)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python current time comparison with other time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585338/python-current-time-comparison-with-other-time)

Comment: Hi. I have tried. But no. I need to have a open and close.

Comment: please write more about the context you are working on and the result you want achieve, possibly with examples. See the guidelines about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi. I solved it with the tip from Joe. I answered no at first but then I tried to change the open time and then it worked, But it is not synchronized with the Swedish zone. Do you have any tips for that? How do I get it to sync with the Swedish time zone? Thanks!